# Activate and deactive ribbon by 1 button VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel worksheet with 2 buttons. First button deactivates ribbon, second activates it. I need to combine both functions into one button.
Code sample:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
End Sub
```

Hope for help.

Comment: Why not use an ActiveX toggle button? This has True/False attributes depending on whether it is depressed or not!

Comment: Because when you close an excel document, toggle button will save his status, but ribbon not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the actual visibility state of the ribbon first.

```
Private Sub cmdToggleRibbon_Click()
    Dim isRibbonVisible As Boolean
    isRibbonVisible = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("Get.ToolBar(7,""Ribbon"")")

    If isRibbonVisible Then
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Else
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
    End If
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = Not isRibbonVisible
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not isRibbonVisible
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = Not isRibbonVisible
End Sub
```